# How to use batch build for a VB.NET project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

In Visual Studio 2008, I am not able to see the *Batch Build* option for VB.NET projects (as for C++ projects).

I am new to VB.NET, but does it have other options to do a batch build rather than creating a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the button appear (written from a Visual Studio 2005 perspective, but probably the same or at least very similar for Visual Studio 2008):

Right click on somewhere on the Visual Studio toolbar and select *Customize...*, then on the *Commands* tab in the *Categories* list, select *Build*.

You should now have a list of Build commands in the *Commands* list, one of which should be *Batch Build...*. Drag and drop that to somewhere on the toolbar.

However, I'm not certain if batch builds are supported for Visual Basic, so I'm not sure if this will help you.

Comment: Drag and drop from the customize dialog does not seem to work with Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1):

[There is no such thing as Batch Build for VB.NET projects](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/2fc4e411-ec38-4772-8745-731a52b08b1f/quotbatch-buildquot-menu-item-now-missing?forum=vbide#4410249d-961d-44b5-94e8-5bcbde1465cb-isAnswer). Even in mixed solutions with only one Visual Basic project, **Batch Build...** is disabled/unavailable.