# Build multiple solution platforms at once?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have created in my project two additional solution platforms:

[image]

My active solution is "AnyCPU", when I press the button to compile the application there is a way to build also the other two platforms in their respective directories?.

This can be done?, maybe using some kind of compiler command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C:..........\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe "C:.......\ .sln /t:build /m:8 /p:RunCodeAnalysis=false;BuildInParallel=True /v:n

Do that for each .sln you got! And put that in a batch file. The compile is out of VS.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using Visual Studio 2013 (which your tag would indicate), you can go to `Build >> Batch Build` and you can put a check mark next to each project/configuration combo you want to build. You can learn more about this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651644.aspx

Apparently though, VB.NET does not support batch builds, as indicated at [this link](http://www.hightechtalks.com/visual-studio-net-ide/batch-build-solutions-vb-projects-347613.html).

Comment: Actually, batch build is available in VS2012 too, and I _think_ I remember seeing it as early as VS6.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2008 this option is available too.

Comment: I can change my wording. The MSDN link that I linked in my answer only had Visual Studio 2012 and 2013 available in their "other versions" drop down, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Interesting... I'm using VS 2013 with General Developer settings and I don't see that Batch Build option on my Build menu. I might have to do a bit more reading on this to find out why that is, unless someone else knows off the top of their head.

Comment: @jmcilhinney -- Try looking at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476010/has-the-batch-build-option-been-removed-in-visual-studio-2012-express

Comment: As it turns out, the Batch Build option is available by default for a C# WinForms project but not a VB WinForms project.  Presumably it can be added manually for VB but I haven't actually tried yet.

Comment: yes I'm using VS2013 (Ultimate) and as pointed by @jmcilhinney now I noticed that I don't have this option in a VB.NET project, I accepted too early the answer, sorry, I still need help with this because this answer does not solves the problem for VBNET

Comment: Also seems is not supported in VB.NET, I've tried this solution but the command is added disabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716981/how-to-use-batch-build-for-vb-net-project-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: @ElektroStudios - What edition of Visual Studio are you using? Express?

Comment: @ElektroStudios - Also, look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066536/cant-access-build-configuration-manager-or-build-configurations-in-visual-c-sha

Comment: @icemanind I commented it in my last comment, VisualStudio 2013 Ultimate.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - That is so weird. I am using the same exact product. Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. It shows up just fine for me. Is there something weird about the solution maybe?

Comment: I think you use C# and thats the reason why it is shown, in my case in C# the option is shown, but in vb.net that feature is hidden and when I force to show it is disabled...

Comment: the "show advanced build configuration" mentioned in the url that you've provided is enabled by default in vs.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - You are correct. Apparent batch builds are not supported for VB.NET projects. That makes no sense since the only difference would be a call to VBC instead of CSC to compile the code. Here is the source from Microsoft support: http://www.hightechtalks.com/visual-studio-net-ide/batch-build-solutions-vb-projects-347613.html

Comment: @icemanind consider merging comments about VB.Net into your answer.